# MX-record email dns

Tags: email, dns, mx-record

Help needed on MX records kung fu.

```
abc.com = 1.1.1.1
def.com = 2.2.2.2
```

abc.com has an MX entry of mail.abc.com with a corresponding A record with the IP address for def.com of 2.2.2.2. 2.2.2.2 is receiving the emails addressed to billy@mail.abc.com in it's addon domain of mail.abc.com. However, users must now address mail to someone@mail.abc.com.

I need this work with people not having to use the "mail" part of the name.

Anybody have some working solutions here?

Answer (score 0):

Your DNS setup looks fine. I think the actual problem in your mail server configuration. I think it is set to only accept mail for `mail.abc.com` and not `abc.com`.